# show text on logo hover in over

Tags: theming, modal-dialogs

I've been testing the various overlay modules trying to find a simple way to implement a very minimalist designed text I want to display when hovering over my logo img at http://stefanbjorklund.info/.

I'm using Zen 5.x theme

Here's what I want to achieve (see the left side under the logo, nevermind the background-color of the emaillink):

[image: Not hovering over logo]

[image: Hovering over logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way to go is jQuery.

1. Create new block with text that you want to show
2. Using CSS, set block position that you want
3. Set `display:none;` for that block
4. Add jQuery script in your block (or implement on some other way).

Script should looks something like:

`jQuery("#logo").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery("#blockId").fadeIn(); //change the blockId with Id of your block
            jQuery("#block-views-projects-block").fadeTo(1000,0.5);
        },
        function () {
            jQuery("#blockId").fadeOut(); //change the blockId with Id of your block
            jQuery("#block-views-projects-block").fadeTo(1000,1);
        }
    );`

Of course, if you add this code in your block, it must to be added into `<script>...</script>` tag.

Comment: This is a perfect and simple solution for the hover script, thanks a bunch. http://stefanbjorklund.info is updated with this. Do you have a suggestion to how I can get the rest of the site greyed out with CSS as on the mockup above?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to ask me, but I edit my post (added .fadeTo on hover), with this looks much better, text is more readable...

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I didn't see your entire comment. Use edited script (with .fadeTo) and thats it...

Comment: :) thanks. I hit enter too soon. This works perfectly. One final question. How do I reverse jQuery("#block-views-projects-block").fadeTo(1000,0.5); when 'unhovering' ?

Comment: I forgot that :), script is edited...also, number 1000 is speed of animation in ms (1000 = 1 second) so you can change that number to adjunct speed. I think that 400 is default for fadeIn and fadeOut, so you can change that number to 400 and everything will be synced...

Comment: superb, thanks a lot. gotta start learning jQuery;)

Comment: You're welcome. jQuery is very easy and useful...